# What does "access_token" mean? in Laravel Passport Social Grant

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I do not understand the meaning of "access_token" in the Laravel Passport Social Grant document with the description that "Access token issued by the specified service provider".

https://github.com/coderello/laravel-passport-social-grant

Answer (score 0):

So actually `access_token` is not really related to the Laravel package itself.
The package is just following OAuth standard. You can read more about it here: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/